# Why am I receiving a 255 Record insertion limit on Oracle 10g using DBExpress? 

Tags: oracle, delphi, dbexpress, ora-03114

I am hitting an brick wall during normal SQL processing

When connected to Oracle 10g from a remote client w/DBEXPRESS,   - using the standard dbxpora.dll  +  oci.dll

When in a transaction, after exactly 255 record insertions, the connection hangs for 30 seconds and returns the error:

> ORA-03114 (as if it lost the connection...)

This happens when inserting 255 records into any table while in a transaction. (when run locally on the db box everything works fine)

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know Oracle databases specifically, but I do know that 255 is a magic number.  It's the maximum value you can express in a single byte.  There's probably something declared as a Byte that's counting your records, and you're overflowing it.  Try rebuilding your entire project with range checking and overflow checking turned on, and see if it raises an exception somewhere when you try to do this.  That should help track it down, if it's actually in code you're compiling.  If it's in one of the libraries, that won't help.

Comment: Maybe you missed the "(when run locally on the db box everything works fine)"

Comment: ...oh. I read that wrong. Thought you meant running your transaction on the DB manually.  In that case, nevermind.  It's still probably an integer overflow, but the problem's in your transport layer somewhere.  If you don't get any good answers here, try reporting it to Oracle.

Comment: thanks...but im thinking your correct in the transport layer...i.e. DBExpress and Oracle10g.